# Importing a Python module from subfolder of another folder using relative path

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path, relative-import

I have the following folder structure,

```
└── project
    ├── A
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── B
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── C
            ├── __init__.py
            └──  module_x.py
```

I want to import all the methods in `module_x.py` into `main.py`. I have tried

```
from ..B.C.module_x import *
```

But I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong? How can this be done using relative import?

Answer (score 1):

```
from project.B.C import foo 
from ...b.c.module_x import foo
```

However, relative imports are only meant to work within one package. If project is a package, then you can use relative imports here. If project is not a package, you cannot.

However, if you're running a script in / and doing something like import project.A.b.foo, then that relative import will succeed because project is now a package. In that case, the following two would be equivalent:

```
from ...B.C import foo
from project.B.C import foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `-m` switch to run python modules as scripts:

```
$ cd project
$ python -m A.main # note no .py
```

This tells python that A.main is a module - python will also scan the current working dir (project) and detect package B - this will make your imports work correctly.